# roslaunch stuck on 'Loading robot model'

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, roslaunch, srdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I'm trying to run a moveit path that I have planned out with the following launch file:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find planar_2d_description)/urdf/planar_2d.urdf" />
    <arg name="srdf_file" default="$(find planar_2d_config)/config/planar_2d.srdf" />
    <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(arg urdf_file)" />
    <param name="robot_description_semantic" command="cat $(arg srdf_file)" />
    <include file="$(find planar_2d_config)/launch/planar_2d_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml"/>
    <node
        pkg="planar_2d_planning"
        type="project_part_one"
        name="planning_node"
        output="screen"
    />
</launch>
```

However, on launch ROS seems to hang up at this step:

`[ INFO] [1428960470.895442847]: Loading robot model 'planar_2d'...`

And if I kill it with ctrl+C:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what():  Unable to connect to move_group action server within allotted time (2)`

I'm at a loss as to what can be causing this. The paths to my urdf and srdf are correct, and I am passing the param the contents of the file with cat, not just the path.

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207093/roslaunch-stuck-on-%27loading-robot-model%27/) by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on ROS Answers with karma: 593 on 2015-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> <include file="$(find planar_2d_config)/launch/planar_2d_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml"/>
> ```

That include is not enough to start MoveIt correctly, which is why you get the `Unable to connect to move_group action server within allotted time (2)` error. Not all services have been started which hangs your application: it is simply waiting for those services to come up.

Do you have any specific reason to want to create this all by hand? The [moveit_setup_assistant](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/MoveIt!_Setup_Assistant) creates a `demo.launch` file for you which starts and configures all the required nodes for a functioning planning pipeline. Take a look at the [demo.launch](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_pr2/blob/f51700705d65ba7f8d6466bddaafe27cc681a086/pr2_moveit_config/launch/demo.launch) from the `pr2_moveit_config` package to see an example (but your `planar_2d_config` should also have one).

As an immediate fix, you could include the `move_group.launch` file from your `planar_2d_config` package, instead of what you're doing now. Use `demo.launch` to see which parameters it needs ([here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_pr2/blob/f51700705d65ba7f8d6466bddaafe27cc681a086/pr2_moveit_config/launch/demo.launch#L19-L24) for the PR2 again).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on 2015-04-15**:
I used the setup assistant to create my config files. Then I had to change a few of them, since I have a 2 DOF arm and am using a custom ik solver. I managed to get it to work by including the planning_context file with the load_robot_description value set to true.